# How can I JSDK of Intellij on MacOSX

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I JSDK of Intellij 9.0 on MacOSX? I want to set it to JDK 1.5 on MacOSX.
I have tried reintall Intellij, but it somehow remember the JSDK of my previous installation.
Can you please tell me how can I reset it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you mean Java version IntelliJ runs under, or Java version IntelliJ uses for projects.

If it's the first:

On OS X applications are usually directories. This is true for IntelliJ.

1. Go into the IntelliJ 9.0.app folder
2. Go into Contents folder
3. edit Info.plist (you will need to have installed Apple's Developer tools)
4. There is a Java subsection that has the setting you need to change.

If it's the second, go to Project Structure -> JDKs and create whatever ones you want.

Comment: I have manually removed the IntelliJ 9.0.app folder and reinstall it. but Info.plist still said it uses 1.6. I want it to use 1.5. However, the Info.plist it does not point to the directory of my 1.5 or 1.6 directory of my Mac env.  How can i set that?

<key>JVMVersion</key>
      <string>1.6*</string>

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your OS X version, you may have no JDK 1.5 installed at all (Snow Leopard 10.6.x comes with no JDK 1.5). In this case IDEA will run under the first JDK it finds, even if it's 1.6 while Info.plist specifies 1.5. If you have both JDK versions installed, Info.plist should work fine, see the [IDEA FAQ](http://jetbrains.net/devnet/docs/DOC-197).

If you want to install JDK 1.5 on Snow Leopard, see another [IDEA FAQ article](http://jetbrains.net/devnet/docs/DOC-1183).